# adob animate JS cannot draw on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Cannot get rectangle drawn on canvas with javascript in Adobe Animate with code below. 
Successful only when using Createjs Ticker function with eventListener. Please note I'm NOT asking about animation -- but just about drawing something on the Canvas.
Am I incurring in a coding or in a conceptual error?
Thanks in advance for kind help to beginner.

```
this.stop();

//Line below not needed as far as I checked (when in in Adobe Animate)
//var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// I get the rectangle and text on Canvas ONLY when I uncomment the three commented lines below

//createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", handleTick);

//function handleTick() {
    alert("ctx 25")
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.strokeRect(20, 20, 100, 100);
    ctx.font = "bold 25px Verdana";
    ctx.fillText("Index", 200, 70);
//}
```

Comment: Lanny thanks indeed for your help. Your post prompted more follow-up questions I intend to post later. For now, please note this: forget abour using Ticker, for I am having NO problem with easeljs (as far as I have experimented with it). My very (stupid, probably) basic question is... why nothing shows up in the canvas when using just ctx? I can't see what's missing in my code. Could this be something peculiar to AdobeAnimate?

Comment: Is it not possible to write pure js in Adobe Animate? Is createjs mandatory?

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the context directly. EaselJS will clear the canvas each time it redraws.

There are a number of ways to add your own content:
1. Ensure it happens *after* the `stage.update()` or after a child's `draw` method
2. Draw to an external canvas, and use that as a source of a Bitmap
3. Draw to EaselJS's display list instead.

Here is how to draw to the stage using EaselJS

```
// You just need to do this once, not on every tick
var shape = new createjs.Shape();
shape.graphics.setLineStyle(5).drawRect(0,0,100,100);
shape.set({x: 20, y: 20}); // You can also set the x/y directly, or offset the shape in the drawRect call
stage.addChild(shape); // Wherever the stage is constructed.

var text = new createjs.Text("Index", "bold 25px Verdana", "#000");
text.set({x: 200, y:70});
stage.addChild(text);
```

Hope that helps!